# Can't deploy Windows Phone App - An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I'm trying to deploy my app to a device and i get the following error

```
Error   27  An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

the odd thing is that the file and project this error relates to are both blank.

It was a WP7 app but i tried converting it to WP8 app in hope of fixing it but that didn't help. Anyone got any ideas how to figure out what's wrong?

the only thing i could find for this error talks about a specific assembly being compiled for the wrong platform. but this is not an option in the Windows Phone project settings

Comment: What version of Studio are you using? What version of the Phone SDK is installed on the development machine?  What's the version of the actual Phone you're targeting?

Comment: VS2012 11.0.51106.01 Update 1, Windows Phone SDK 8.0, and trying to deploy to a WP8 phone (lumia 920)

Comment: I updated to VS2012 Update 2 but still get the issue

Comment: If you create a new "hello world" type project from the wizard targeting Phone 8, does it work?

Comment: ok so i have made some progress, I pulled out my old 7.1 HTC and i can deploy my app to it but not my 8.0 Nokia. Also i tried a new WP8 project and this deploys ok to my Nokia

Comment: Also i rolled back my conversion of the project to a WP8 project. So its still a 7.1 project

Answer (score 1):

Check the files in your project. Files that are not part of the project should be marked as "Buid Action = none" and "Copy to Output Directory = Do not copy". Some examples are file files "text". Try this, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get any conversion warnings when you converted the project?  I've worked around problems like this in the past by creating a new Windows Phone solution, re-creating the same projects in the new solution, creating any needed sub-folders into those projects, and then copying over the code and content files.  This is usually quick if there aren't a lot of projects & folders.

Comment: ok so i tried creating a new project and copying the classes/content and third party dll's but i get the same error. I'm wondering if its caused by a dll i'm using. oh an i rolled back to a 7.1 project but you can still deploy this to win 8 can't you?

Comment: Yes, most WP7.1 apps can be deployed on WP8 and will run just fine, although I've had some that deployed but didn't run properly.  But I haven't seen one that deployed on WP7 but not WP8.  It makes me think that you might have copied over WMAppManifest.xml code that is no longer compatible, but I thought Visual Studio would catch stuff like that at compile time.  It is possible that a third-party DLL (e.g. a controls library) that you are using targets WP7 and needs to be updated for WP8, but I wouldn't think that would be an issue at deployment.  Not sure what changed for deployment in WP8.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the case with you, or if you've already solved the issue (since it is an old thread), but this happens sometimes when you target the wrong CPU type. For example, your project targets x86 while you have a 64-bit machine.

Follow these steps to (hopefully) fix the issue:

- Go to project properties
- Go to **Build** tab
- Select **Any CPU** from Platform dropdown
- Save and recompile